# Raphael JS Free Transform a Class or ID

Tags: css, class, raphael, transform

I have some difficulties and would like your help. 
I want to apply a FreeTransform in some objects with a particular class or id. 
For example ... Within my HTML, I want to put an image gallery. And I would like the script freetransform apply to all images that have a specific class. 
I have an example of what I did so far.

```
var r = Raphael(document.getElementById('workspace'));
var img = r.image('http://www.porcopedia.com/images/thumb/Simbolo_Goi%C3%A1s.jpg/600px-Simbolo_Goi%C3%A1s.jpg', 10, 10, 200, 200);

register(img);


function register(el) {
    el.data('dragged', false);

    el.click(function() {
            // Toggle handles on click if no drag occurred
            if ( !this.data('dragged') ) {
                    if ( this.freeTransform.handles.center === null ) {
                            this.toFront();

                            this.freeTransform.showHandles();
                    } else {
                            this.freeTransform.hideHandles();
                    }
            }
    });

    r.freeTransform(el, {attrs: {
        fill: 'black',
       stroke: '#111'
    }, drag: true,
    keepRatio: ['axisX', 'axisY','bboxCorners'],
    size: 6,
    scale: [ 'axisX', 'axisY', 'bboxCorners', 'bboxSides' ],
    rotate: true,
    draw: ['bbox', 'circle']}, function(ft, events) {
            if ( events.indexOf('drag start') !== -1 ) {
                    el.data('dragged', false);
            }

            if ( events.indexOf('drag') !== -1 ) {
                    el.data('dragged', true);
            }
    }).hideHandles();
}
```

[Example JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/murilobu/LJTPU/4/)

Comment: could also be when the object entered the workspace, activate freetransform.

Comment: I think there's a problem with freetransform being downloaded, so I'm guessing it may make it trickier for people to play with.